# Writing to multiple Filechannels repetitively

Tags: java, nio, imagej, filechannel

Here is some code i made to write succesively and repetitively to multiple filechannels.

The files get made, there are no errors, but nothing gets written.
The important part is where the buffer is written : "listofChan[j].write(buff);"  . Why is this not working?

```
    FileChannel[] listofChan = new FileChannel[mStackHeight];
    FileOutputStream[] outputFiles = new FileOutputStream[mStackHeight];

    ByteBuffer buff = ByteBuffer.allocate(mStackWidth * 2); //2 byte integers
    ShortBuffer SB = buff.asShortBuffer();

    ImageProcessor ip;

    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < mStackHeight; i++) {
            outputFiles[i] = new FileOutputStream(new File(mSavepath + "\\T_" + i + ".dat"), true);
            listofChan[i] = outputFiles[i].getChannel();
        }
        System.out.println("File streams created successfully.");

        for (int z = 0; z < mStackSz; z++) { //all slices in stack
            ip = mStack.getProcessor(z + 1);
            ip = ip.convertToShortProcessor();
            short[] Pixels = (short[]) ip.getPixels();
            for (int j = 0; j < mStackHeight; j++) {  //all lines in one frame
                SB.clear();                     
                SB.put(Pixels, j * mStackWidth, mStackWidth);
                listofChan[j].write(buff);                    
            }

            System.out.println("line " + z + " " + listofChan[mStackWidth-1].position());
            // System.out.println("Image line : " z-1+ p/mStackWidth );
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < mStackHeight; i++) {
            outputFiles[i].close();
        }

        System.out.println("Buffer contents written to file.");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("File IO exception : " + e.toString());

    }
```

Okay, I've found the solution:

I needed to add `buff.clear()` on a line just above `SB.clear();`
because after writing the `ByteBuffer`, the read/write postition is at end of the buffer, so it cannot be written from further. The same for the `IntBuffer`, this also needs to be reset separately because the positions of both views are independent (I'm assuming ...).

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to flip your byte buffer before it is written. It is still in read/put mode.

Comment: Correct, and `compact()` it after the `write()`.

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to go to such a low level programming to achieve your task. There are already tools available in ImageJ to save each channel to a separate file.

For example, you can do so by choosing *Plugins > Bio-Formats > Bio-Formats Exporter* (this plugin is included in Fiji) and it will present the following dialog:

[image: Bioformats dialog to allow saving separate files]

You can use the [Recorder](http://imagej.net/Introduction_into_Macro_Programming#The_recorder) to get the required Java code:

```java
IJ.run(imp, "Bio-Formats Exporter", "save=C:\\Path\\To\\Your\\File.ome.tif write_each_channel compression=Uncompressed");
```

---

If you really want to interact with the exporter on a lower level, have a look at the [source code of `Exporter.java`](https://github.com/openmicroscopy/bioformats/blob/master/components/bio-formats-plugins/src/loci/plugins/out/Exporter.java).

Comment: Thanks for the info. Will this also work for extremely large vitual stacks (10000 images and over)?

Comment: I haven't tried, but it should. If it doesn't, it's a bug (and [should be reported](http://imagej.net/Bug_reporting_best_practices)). So why don't you just try it?